# Несколько сайтов на wordpress на одном хостинге

Tags: wordpress, хостинг

Можно ли на хостинг установить wordpress сразу для нескольких сайтов? Если да, то как?

Сейчас у меня для каждого сайта на хостинге стоит отдельно wordpress. Но дело в том, что это жрет очень много памяти, хотя все файлы, кроме конфига, одинаковы.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress не допускает совместного использования файлов ядра для нескольких сайтов. Есть решение WordPress Multisite, но там свои ограничения. По сути, это все равно связанные сайты.

Так что под каждый сайт нужна отдельная установка WordPress. На моем виртуальном сервере несколько десятков клиентских сайтов и каждый использует свои файлы  WordPress.

Comment: Ещё как допускает! Достаточно понимания того, что в конфиге можно задавать условия для `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Другой вопрос чем это чревато и что еще нужно делать для конкретного сайта.

Answer (score 0):

> можно ли на хостинг установить wordpress сразу для нескольких сайтов?Если да, то как?

Есть несколько способов использовать один дистрибутив для нескольких сайтов. Навскидку:

1. [Стандартная сеть](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8)
2. [Использовать разные префиксы таблиц](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B8_WordPress)

Можно применить и более изощрённые методы.

Все способы имеют свои особенности и нюансы. Напр.  нужно отдельно замрочитья с реврайтами для правильных ссылок на роботс или генерить его налету.

Но это НЕ решение проблемы с нагрузкой. Для уменьшения нагрузки нужно оптимизировать сайты или/и менять хостинг.